# Can send SNMP requests from manager to multiple agents concurrently?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I require to send get requests to several snmp agents from a client process.

I have implemented client/agent based on below urls
http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/snmp/create-snmp-client-in-java-using-snmp4j/
http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/snmp/creating-snmp-agent-server-in-java-using-snmp4j/

I would like to know whether the client/manager can send requests to the agents concurrently? (e.g. using background threads within the process)
or whether it would be necessary to poll each agent individually?

From the samples,
CommunityTarget has address set as udp:127.0.0.1/161 - which is then used in the snmp 'get' request.
The agent has address set as 0.0.0.0/2001 - which is used when creating TransportMappings.

I don't understand how the addressing is working / how I would configure to handle agents at other/non local IP addresses?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For question #1:

You are asking about synchronous vs. asynchronous API usage.
Google "snmp4j asynchronous" for examples.
This is orthogonal to single-thread vs. multi-thread.
Ie. you can have a single-thread application which asynchronously sends requests and handles multiple agents' responses.
As an example, the MIMIC Recorder is a single-threaded, asynchronous app.
Multi-thread is only needed for complicated applications which handle complicated management state machines.

For question #2:

It looks like the sample code only connects to the agent 127.0.0.1 on the local system. To connect remotely, you would have to use the IP address where the agent is running.

Comment: thank you I have posted a new/related question 'How should an snmp client receive responses from multiple snmp agents?'